# HTML input covering A attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a search bar that usiing `AJAX` to bring up results, but the input box covers the first result rendering it unclickable (you can see it, you just can't click on it), I've tried everything but i cannot make it clickable. It's just the first one too, the rest you can click on.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>Untitled Document</title> 
    <style>

      body
      {
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background:#ccc;
      }

      #display ul
      {
        z-index:200;
        list-style: none;
        margin-top:72px;
        width: 330px;
      }

      #display li
      {
        z-index:200;
        display: block;
        padding: 4px;
        background-color: #eee;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #367;
      }

      #clear
        { clear:both; }

      #search{
        position:absolute;
      }

      a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration:none;
      }

      .cf:before, .cf:after{
         content:"";
         display:table;
      }

     .cf:after{
       clear:both;
     }

     .cf{
       zoom:1;
     }  

     .form-wrapper {
       width: 450px;
       padding: 30px;
       margin: 1px auto 1px auto;
   position:absolute;
       z-index:100;
       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
       border-radius: 10px;
       clear:both;
     }

    .form-wrapper input {
      padding-left:10px;
      width: 330px;
      height: 40px;
      padding: 0px 0px;
      float: left;    
      font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
      border: 0;
      background: #eee;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px; 
      margin-left:10px;     
    }

    .form-wrapper input:focus {
      outline: 0;
      background: #fff;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
      box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
    }

    .form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: #999;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: italic;
    }

    .form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder {
      color: #999;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: italic;
    }

    .form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: #999;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: italic;
    }    

    .form-wrapper button {
      overflow: visible;
      position: relative;
      float: right;
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 40px;
      width: 110px;
      font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      background: #d83c3c;
      -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
      text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
    }   

    .form-wrapper button:hover{     
      background: #e54040;
    }   

    .form-wrapper button:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
      border-style: solid solid solid none;
      border-color: transparent #d83c3c transparent;
      top: 12px;
      left: -6px;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function fill(Value)
  {
    $('#name').val(Value);
    $('#display').hide();
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    /*
      $("#search").click(function (){
        $("#display").css('display' , 'none');
      });
    */

    $("#name").keyup(function() {
      var name = $('#name').val();
      if(name=="")
      {
        $("#display").html("");
      }
      else
      {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "backend.php",
          data: "name="+ name ,
          success: function(html){
            $("#display").html(html).show();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

    </script>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="search">
  <form method="post" action="searcher.php" class="form-wrapper cf">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search User Pages" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" required>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Search</button>
  </form>

  <div id="display"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Backend.php

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
  $name=trim($_POST['name']);
  $query2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username LIKE '%$name%' LIMIT 5");
  echo "<ul>";
  while($query3=mysql_fetch_array($query2))
  {
?>

     <a href='page.php?user=<?php echo $query3['username']; ?>'><li onclick='fill("<?php echo $query3['username']; ?>")'><?php echo $query3['username']; ?></li></a>

<?php
  }
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Since you're floating both your button and input, you're taking them out of the flow of your dom. You may need to add clear:both to your display div to get the contents to go appear after the input. Better: don't float those elements.  Finally, your list markup is a bit weird. Anchor tags usually go inside list item tags.  `<li onclick...><a href=...>`

Comment: I removed the float from the input, without the float on the submit button it would not be next to it, I also added clear: both to #display but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the padding of your form-wrapper element.  It appears that the padding is covering the display div. I changed the CSS for .form-wrapper, replacing the padding to

```
.form-wrapper {
   width: 450px;
   padding-left: 30px;
   padding-top:30px;
   margin: 1px auto 1px auto;
   position:absolute;
   z-index:100;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   clear:both;
 }
```

and it works.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6HuyX/%20JSFiddle):